# best way to encode a path to be used as html-valid "id" or "name" tag

Tags: php, javascript, html, path, encode

I have an editable filesystem where user can submit changes in a form.

I would like to use the path of the files as NAME or ID Tags.

Since i doubt i am the first facing this, there might be a better approach.

Examples:

```
path: ../../disney/mouse/mickey.php
```

Known restrictions:

```
Jquery: no periods (.) and colons (:) 
HTML : Only letter, digits,hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")
HTML5: All but no spaces ( ) and at least 1 char.
```

It is required that PHP AND JAVASCRIPT can easily encode/decode the string in both ways. 
atm i do it by replacing "/" & "." with unusual patterns.

Which encoding you advise and is there something that even SHRINKS the path but stays unique??

Regards :>

EDIT: USers can alter and edit the code from the files. Why do you advise me to use an additional input for each field which links the path with the content? i don't see the point since its not a problem if the name or id tags are properly encoded.

Comment: I wouldn't use the path either but rather a numeric identifier.  Users never supposed to see field names - why bother to write something meaningful there?

Comment: the file names are already known to the user since he uploads them. saved are the files outside the html_directory even unnecessary with random containing folder.

Comment: So, you are making things unnecessarily complicated, making yourself  a need of creation a filename validation function. `*shrug*` some people likes to invent problems out of nowhere...

Comment: @Your Common Sense lol, yes you might be right. but i really don't see how you could submit a filepath and its content in 1 input-field other than using NAME-tag or appending the filename at the end with a unique delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using your values as identifiers. This is not good practice and this is why you are encountering this problem. But if you want to do it anyway...

If you want to use a single string for all languages, you need to create a single string that excludes all the restricted characters found in each language. If restricted characters are part of the path, things become more difficult to keep unique. I would recommend you take the full path, then use a preg_replace() to change all characters that are not expected to underscores.

```
$old = '../../disney/mouse/mickey.php';
$new = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $old);
echo $new;
//Outputs: "______disney_mouse_mickey_php"
```

You will definitely want to modify this to add in more characters that are allowed. The less that you restrict, the less likely you are to have a collision of non-unique id/name attributes.

If you want a method that is less prone to having a possible non-unique id/name, then you can wrap your path in md5() (PHP) to create a md5 hash. This is less friendly to read, but should be unique enough for most non-critical purposes.

```
$old = '../../disney/mouse/mickey.php';
$new = md5($old);
echo $new;
//Outputs: "403d07916233847221263553573c5321"
```

In response to your comments, here is my final attempt. This /custom/ function will encode a path that is both unique and readable in the source. This will also allow you decode into your original path string. The allowed characters and escape character are customizable so that you can find one that is usable in all languages you require.

```
function customPathEncode($old)
{
    $chars_allowed = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    $escape_char = '%';
    $new = '';

    $old_length = strlen($old);
    for($i = 0; $i < $old_length; ++$i)
    {
        if(false === strpos($chars_allowed, $old[$i]))
        {
            $new .= $escape_char.bin2hex($old[$i]);
        }
        else
        {
            $new .= $old[$i];
        }
    }

    return $new;
}
echo customPathEncode('../../disney/mouse/mickey.php');
//Output: "%2e%2e%2f%2e%2e%2fdisney%2fmouse%2fmickey%2ephp"
```

Comment: i already use that approach. but am looking for a better, maybe JS and PHP built in way. or some inbuilt encoding function which only use letters and diggits.

Comment: base64_encode() will produce a unique letters and digits only string, but it is also unreadable just like md5. The function you are describing, that will create a unique but remain readable, does not exist. You will have to create that yourself.

Comment: they need to be decodeable by js too. writing a custom function to do so requires lag on the clientside.

Comment: The time to encode/decode a string in a custom JS function is negligible. This is not an intensive process, and will not introduce noticeable decrease in performance if implemented properly and used on a modern browser. A custom function is the only way to accomplish what you are asking. There is no native function, because what you intend to do is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no point in doing this.

You can always process your data as values, not identifiers, like everyone does.
Store your path as a field's value with some generic name. Not a big deal.

Comment: can't agree. 1. u suggest me to use double of input types than my approach. 2. i need the path's to be fastly accessible for ajax and jquery modifications. 3. Google as well as Microsoft handles some of their forms too with path-strings as names. i don't know exactly how they encode though, it only contains %,letters and diggits.

Comment: I am not suggesting to double anything. if you need fast modifications, use JSON. I don't understand your problem. Looks like a whim to me.

Comment: all the files are editable through codemirror. content and path have to be bound. you suggest me to use two input fields, one with the content and a simple id/name and another with the value "path" and name/id which connects them to the appropriate content field. 2 Fields how else?

Comment: oh yeah. such a doubling you mean. I see now. you are going to save  a great lot of fields. My congratulations.

Comment: thank you. I wouldn't mind submitting double fields but i think your approach complicates the whole thing. Let me ask you: HOW would you link the 2 fields with EACH other? i will give it a try since you are a most respected person :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **Java**, and I've solved this by encoding/decoding paths to/from ***hex*** representation of the file path.

I'm not very familiar with **PHP**, but I guess you could use [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) & [hex2bin](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) for this purpose.

Hope this helps...